# Facelet does not convert formatted currency correctly

Tags: jsf, input, currency, facelets, converters

I have the follwing code inside a facelet page:

```
<h:inputNumber value="bean.property">
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
</h:inputNumber
```

The converter is because there can be a kind of default value inside the input field, which comes from the bean property. Everything is rendered correctly. The value inside the input field is rendered with an "€" character (e.g. "1.453 €".

When I submit the form there comes an error up:

```
"nameOfInputField" konnte nicht als ein Geldbetrag erkannt werden '304,00 â¬'
```

In english it is some like:

```
"nameOfInputField" could not be regognized as an amount of money '304,00 â¬'
```

Please have a look at the "€" character. It seems to be printed as "â¬". While it was rendered correctly before submitting the form, now it looks like "â¬" inside the error message and inside the input field.

All pages are encoded in UTF-8.

What is the reason for this error?
How can fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> â¬

This is typical for the € from an original UTF-8 source which is incorrectly been decoded using ISO-8859-1. Here's a small snippet which demonstrates that:

```
System.out.println(new String("€".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

> *All pages are encoded in UTF-8.*

You're likely talking about **response** encoding. You need to set the **request** encoding as well.

To set the encoding for `GET` requests (basically: URI encoding), you need to consult the appserver specific documentation. As it's unclear which one you're using, here's a Tomcat targeted example: [`<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" />`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html). To set the encoding for `POST` requests, you need to create a simple filter which does [`request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) if it is `null`. More background information and hints can be found in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest).

Comment: I'm using Tomcat. I used the filter-way. Worked fine. Thanks. Man you realy know how things work!

Comment: @c0d3x in addition to accepting the answer that worked, you are also welcome to upvote it

Comment: I have to register myself to do that. I will do that during the next days or something.

Answer (score 1):

Put this ontop of your facelets page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

It will instruct the facelets parser.

Comment: Ah yes, I always overlook/forgot the Facelets part. But you're right, +1.

Comment: Thanks you for answering, but the xml tag is on top of all of my facelet pages.

Comment: @c0d3x check what is the response encoding (using your browser "page info")

Comment: Maybe it's been overridden somewhere? Do you have any `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">` header? Or maybe it's server impl/version or Facelets version specific? Can you tell a bit more about them?